# Running javascript code in golang

Tags: javascript, ajax, go

I need some javascript code inside go code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)
func work(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    fmt.Printf("<script>console.log('javascript working')</script>")

}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", work)
    http.ListenAndServe(":4000", nil)
}
```

Running it in browser and see browser's console window there is nothing to see. How do I run javascript code in go code? Because using ajax with golang it is difficult.

Comment: Craft a **proper** response: Just as a starter: Set the Content-Type, send a full HTML document. Step back and think about what your code does and why a browser should "execute JavaScript code" given what your code does. Then fix. This is totally unrelated to Go and AJAX.

Comment: @Volker is right. This has nothing to do with golang. One would assume if you were trying to invoke a code written in javascript within the golang program execution.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with running javascript in Go.

Comment: You are not writing to w, but to stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple javascript code running in go code is

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    hello := "hello yu bn"
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, `<html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
            <h1>Go Timer (ticks every second!)</h1>
            <div id="output"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log("`+hello+`");
            </script>
            </body>
            </html>`)

    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":9000", nil)
}
```

it is nice! Check browser console!